# spring petclinic compilation errors in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, spring-mvc

Downloaded spring petclinic example from github and opened in eclipse as an existing maven project, It is failing with compilation errors. The java version is 1.7.0.51, spring version from pom.xml is 4.1.1.RELEASE.

the compilation errors are :- 
The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for org.hamcrest.core.CombinableMatcher$CombinableBothMatcher. Fix the build path then try building this project

The type org.hamcrest.core.CombinableMatcher$CombinableBothMatcher cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Please let me know your suggestions. thanks

Comment: It sounds like the project's pom does not include `hamcrest-core` or `hamcrest-all` as a dependency. Can you post the contents of the pom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add this to your pom dependancies :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
    <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

the m2 repositories junit411.jar and hamcrest.jar though present were corrupt. upon deleting them and letting maven redownload them fixed my compilation errors. thanks